# VB.net HttpWebRequest 403 error

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403

My code is 100% working but when I try filling up the forms under yelp.com it gives me 403 error. Here is my code:

```
    Dim cweb As String = "http://www.yelp.com/biz_share?bizid=T6XCD1_eLEk3LaSp8C7E1g&amp;return_url=%2Fbiz%2Fmr-c-los-angeles-2"
    Dim POST As String = "csrftok=6cc5dea3ff8bf8f404f1e7a4951342cb2f132a17cb625a3988c50027d358285d&context=pyZQEaHS1YbhP3EEsTKGww&action_submit=1&emails=samplemail@gmail.com&emails=&emails=&unauth_name=Test+Name&unauth_email=testemail%40email.com&note=How%27s+it+going%3F"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer

    request = CType(WebRequest.Create(cweb), HttpWebRequest)
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = POST.Length
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.CookieContainer = tempCookies


    Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POST)
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies)
    Dim postreader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreader.ReadToEnd
    response.Close()
```

The web form I am basing is this:

```
http://www.yelp.com/biz_share?bizid=T6XCD1_eLEk3LaSp8C7E1g&amp;return_url=%2Fbiz%2Fmr-c-los-angeles-2
```

On other web forms I am able to fill-up and send them, does this mean that yelp.com won't let you send any webrequest? I am really confused right now. Any help will be gladly accepted thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that 403 is a forbidden error, I would assume that Yelp is blocking post requests from unauthenticated addresses.

Comment: is there any way to bypass the block?

Comment: Not unless you are able to authenticate with the server at yelp.  At least, no legal way.

Comment: The best place to start is with yelp.com - see the [Yelp for Developers](http://www.yelp.com/developers) section. I don't know if they allow remote posting of content, but that would be the best place to start your search.

Comment: I will be exploring through that link. Thanks I hope I can find something useful along the way.

Comment: The form value you are submitting "csrftok" looks like a nonce value. A nonce is generally used to disallow repeat attacks, which honestly may be what you are doing. You should first request the page, extract the hidden inputs "csrftok" and "context" from the response and post with those values. Additionally, you may receive cookies from the response which you will also want to send with your post. That may work, though there may be additional measures that have taken to prevent automated submissions like yours.

Answer (score 0):

The csrftok will change for each user / session, the 403 is there because your authentication data is bad / the csrftok is not valid for the session. You need to go to the page before this (Or a login page or similar) to get the correct token.